# How to change the size of label in bar chart

Tags: c#, mschart

How can I change size of only one label on axisX in bar chart. I want to change only first label that's coming from string.

c# code:

```
string pursue = _getLabel(reportLanguage, "Pursue_Noble_Goals");
string increase = _getLabel(reportLanguage, "Increase_Empathy");                  
string give = _getLabel(reportLanguage, "Give_Yourself");

chart.Series[1].Points.AddXY(pursue, Convert.ToDouble(_removeSomething(qas.PursueNobleGoalsScore, _str)));
chart.Series[1].Points[0].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128);                                       
chart.Series[1].Points.AddXY(increase, Convert.ToDouble(_removeSomething(qas.IncreaseEmpathyScore, _str)));
chart.Series[1].Points[1].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 192);
chart.Series[1].Points.AddXY(give, Convert.ToDouble(_removeSomething(qas.GiveYourselfScore, _str)));                                     
chart.Series[1].Points[2].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 216, 25, 33);
chart.Series[1].Points.AddXY(exercise, Convert.ToDouble(_removeSomething(qas.ExcerciseOptimismScore, _str)));
chart.Series[1].Points[3].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 216, 25, 33);
```

Comment: Which chart controls you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you have posted, suppose if you want to change the first point axis label which is "Pursue_Noble_Goals" to something like "Pursue_Noble_Thoughts", the following line of code should do the trick:

```
chart.Series[1].Points[0].AxisLabel = "Pursue_Noble_Thoughts";
```